# GET internal server error (500) with Next.js in only one API route

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js, cors, vercel

I hope you're able to help me. I get a 500 response in one of the Next.js API routes. I deployed my app on Vercel & added the `vercel.json` CORS configuration file based on [Vercel documentation](https://vercel.com/guides/how-to-enable-cors).

There's some weird behavior as I can access and get the right response on all of the other API routes except this one.

To be precise, I `fetch` data from a different domain/URL. The problem occurs ONLY in production - in development mode it's all great and no errors in the terminal.

Any idea what's going on? Thanks in advance.

`https://mindescape-cms.vercel.app/api/articles` | `GET`

[image]

**vercel.json**

```
{
  "headers": [
    {
      "source": "/api/(.*)",
      "headers": [
        { "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "value": "true" },
        { "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "value": "*" },
        { "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "value": "GET,OPTIONS,PATCH,DELETE,POST,PUT" },
        {
          "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
          "value": "X-CSRF-Token, X-Requested-With, Accept, Accept-Version, Content-Length, Content-MD5, Content-Type, Date, X-Api-Version"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**UPDATE!** I checked the logs on Vercel and it says:

```
info  - Loaded env from /var/task/.env.local
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:399:5)
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (node:_http_outgoing:663:11)
    at _res.setHeader (/var/task/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:180:24)
    at sendJson (/var/task/node_modules/next/dist/server/api-utils/node.js:195:9)
    at apiRes.json (/var/task/node_modules/next/dist/server/api-utils/node.js:360:31)
    at handler (/var/task/.next/server/pages/api/articles.js:126:29)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async Object.apiResolver (/var/task/node_modules/next/dist/server/api-utils/node.js:372:9)
    at async NextNodeServer.runApi (/var/task/node_modules/next/dist/server/next-server.js:514:9)
    at async Object.fn (/var/task/node_modules/next/dist/server/next-server.js:828:35) {
  code: 'ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT'
}
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:399:5)
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (node:_http_outgoing:663:11)
    at _res.setHeader (/var/task/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:180:24)
    at sendJson (/var/task/node_modules/next/dist/server/api-utils/node.js:195:9)
    at apiRes.json (/var/task/node_modules/next/dist/server/api-utils/node.js:360:31)
    at handler (/var/task/.next/server/pages/api/articles.js:126:29)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async Object.apiResolver (/var/task/node_modules/next/dist/server/api-utils/node.js:372:9)
    at async NextNodeServer.runApi (/var/task/node_modules/next/dist/server/next-server.js:514:9)
    at async Object.fn (/var/task/node_modules/next/dist/server/next-server.js:828:35) {
  code: 'ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT'
}
RequestId: b1ea1aba-1e68-4782-bdfa-4b18c6c60cec Error: Runtime exited with error: exit status 1
Runtime.ExitError
```

I know what it means but I double checked my API route code and I don't see anywhere sending double response. I make sure I immediately return to pause the execution. Below my full API code. What is wrong here?

**/api/articles/index.js**

```
const handler = async (req, res) => {
  //Check rate limit
  const rateLimitOk = rateLimiterMiddleware(req, res, rateLimiter);

  if (!rateLimitOk) return;

  if (req.method !== 'GET' && req.method !== 'POST' && req.method !== 'PATCH') {
    res.status(400).json({ message: 'Invalid request method. Accepted: GET, POST, PATCH.' });
    return;
  }

  if (req.method === 'GET') {
    let client;
    try {
      client = await connectDb();
    } catch (error) {
      res.status(500).json({ message: 'Connecting to the database failed.' });
      return;
    }

    const database = client.db('mindescape');
    const collection = database.collection('articles');

    let articles;
    try {
      articles = await collection.find({}).sort({ creationDate: -1 }).toArray();
    } catch (error) {
      res.status(500).json({ message: 'Connecting to the database failed.' });
      client.close();
      return;
    }

    //Get articles data with current user data (e.g. user could change profile img in the meantime so to keep data always up to date Im retreiving current user data)

    const collection2 = database.collection('users');
    try {
      //Getting all users
      const users = await collection2.find({}).toArray();
      const actualDataToReturn = getArticlesWithCurrentUserData(articles, users);

      const isAuthenticated = await checkIfAuthenticated(req, res);

      //Remove from each article item => comments => user email (I don't want to expose user emails to strangers)
      if (!isAuthenticated) {
        const articlesWithoutSensitiveData = actualDataToReturn.map(article => {
          const comments =
            article.comments &&
            article.comments.map(item => {
              delete item.email;
              return { ...item };
            });
          return { ...article, comments };
        });
        res.status(200).json({
          quantity: articlesWithoutSensitiveData.length,
          articles: articlesWithoutSensitiveData,
          message: 'The list of published articles.',
        });
        client.close();
        return;
      }
      //If authenticated user, return full data
      res.status(200).json({
        quantity: actualDataToReturn.length,
        articles: actualDataToReturn,
        message: 'The list of published articles.',
      });
      client.close();
      return;
    } catch (error) {
      res.status(500).json({ message: 'Retreiving published articles failed.' });
      client.close();
      return;
    }
  }

  if (req.method === 'POST') {
    const { title, excerpt, body, mainImage } = req.body;

    //If user is not authenticated, request will fail
    const isAuthenticated = await checkIfAuthenticated(req, res);

    if (!isAuthenticated) return;

    //Checking if inputs are NOT EMPTY
    if (title.length === 0 || excerpt.length === 0 || body.length === 0 || !mainImage) {
      res.status(400).json({ message: 'Submission failed. Input fields cannot be empty.' });
      return;
    }

    //Checking if title contains forbidden hash '#' symbol
    if (title.includes('#')) {
      res.status(400).json({ message: 'Remove # from an article title.' });
      return;
    }

    let client;

    try {
      client = await connectDb();
    } catch (err) {
      res.status(500).json({ message: 'Connecting to the database failed.' });
      return;
    }

    const database = client.db('mindescape');
    const articles = database.collection('articles');

    //Checking if article with the same title already exists
    try {
      const articleWithSameTitle = await articles
        .find({
          title: { $regex: new RegExp(title, 'i') },
        })
        .toArray();

      if (articleWithSameTitle.length >= 1) {
        res.status(400).json({ message: 'Article with the same title already exists.' });
        client.close();
        return;
      }
    } catch (err) {
      res.status(500).json({ message: 'Inserting data failed.' });
      client.close();
      return;
    }

    //Inserting article to database
    let result;
    try {
      result = await articles.insertOne({
        ...req.body,
        ...(req.body._id && { _id: new ObjectId(req.body._id) }),
        creationDate: new Date(),
      });

      res.status(200).json({
        message: 'Article successfully added and is now published.',
        data: { ...result },
      });
    } catch (err) {
      res.status(500).json({ message: 'Inserting data failed.' });
      client.close();
      return;
    }

    //Check if article exists in => drafts - if it does -> remove it from drafts to avoid having the same article in 'published' and 'drafts
    const drafts = database.collection('drafts');
    const publishedArticleId = result.insertedId; //new ObjectId(id);

    const foundItem = await drafts.find({ _id: publishedArticleId }).toArray();

    if (foundItem[0]) {
      await drafts.deleteOne({ _id: publishedArticleId });
      client.close();
      return;
    }

    client.close();
  }

  if (req.method === 'PATCH') {
    const { title } = req.body;

    //Check if no title && if title contains forbidden hash '#' symbol
    const correctTitle = validateTitleInput(title, res);
    if (!correctTitle) return;

    let client;

    try {
      client = await connectDb();
    } catch (error) {
      res.status(500).json({ message: 'Connecting to the database failed.' });
      return;
    }

    const database = client.db('mindescape');
    const articles = database.collection('articles');

    if (!req.body._id) {
      res.status(400).json({ message: 'You cannot update non existing article.' });
      client.close();
      return;
    }

    const dataToSend = { ...req.body };
    delete dataToSend._id;

    //Get article that's supposed to be corrected
    const token = await getToken({ req });
    let article;

    try {
      article = await articles.find({ _id: new ObjectId(req.body._id) }).toArray();
    } catch (error) {
      res.status(500).json({ message: 'Failed to validate user permission.' });
      client.close();
      return;
    }

    //Validate user permission
    if (token.role === 'editor' && token._id !== article[0].authorId) {
      res.status(401).json({ message: 'No permission to modify this document.' });
      client.close();
      return;
    }

    //Update article
    try {
      const item = await articles.updateOne(
        { _id: new ObjectId(req.body._id) },
        {
          $set: { ...dataToSend },
          $currentDate: { lastModified: true },
        }
      );
      res.status(200).json({
        data: { ...item },
        message: 'Article has been successfully updated.',
      });
      client.close();
      return;
    } catch (error) {
      res.status(500).json({ message: 'Submitting data failed.' });
      client.close();
      return;
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Have you read the error message? This doesn't appear to be a CORS error. The issue instead stems from an incorrect JSON response body (it looks like HTML rather than JSON).

Comment: Oh it could bring some confusion as on the client side I tried to await and parse response with `res.json()` method. Since there's nothing to parse, it threw that error `is not valid JSON bla bla`. I may crop this screenshot to avoid confusions.

Comment: No it's not a cors error, if it was, you wouldn't be able to see the status code. There is something going wrong in the backend with this route. Probably there is nothing you can do on the client side to resolve this issue. You have to fix it on the server side

Comment: I will deeply take a look. Thanks for defining a direction ;)

Comment: @derprischer I put Vercel server log.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found where the problem occured. The problem occured at the line where I am calling the function `checkIfAuthenticated(req, res)`.

```
const isAuthenticated = await checkIfAuthenticated(req, res);

      //Remove from each article item => comments => user email (I don't want to expose user emails to strangers)
      if (!isAuthenticated) {
        const articlesWithoutSensitiveData = actualDataToReturn.map(article => {
          const comments =
            article.comments &&
            article.comments.map(item => {
              delete item.email;
              return { ...item };
            });
          return { ...article, comments };
        });
        res.status(200).json({
          quantity: articlesWithoutSensitiveData.length,
          articles: articlesWithoutSensitiveData,
          message: 'The list of published articles.',
        });
        client.close();
        return;
      }
```

Since I outsourced this function I forgot that in the function body, I check if the token exists, and if not I return the response so this caused the problem and 2 responses being sent.

**checkIfAuthenticated.js**

```
import { getToken } from 'next-auth/jwt';

const checkIfAuthenticated = async (req, res) => {
  const token = await getToken({ req });

  if (!token) {
    res.status(401).json({ message: 'Protected resource, no access granted.' });
    return false;
  }

  return true;
};
```

Problem solved and I can retreive my lovely data.